# Laravel Error Argument 1 passed to method must be an instance of App\Model, instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection given

Tags: laravel, eloquent, many-to-many

I have these 3 models:

### product

```
    class Product extends Model

    {
        public function categories()
        {
            return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class);
        }
        public function getPriceAttribute($price)
        {
            $categories=$this->categories;
            //dd($categories->first()->validCoupons());  //dd#1
            $coupons =collect(new Coupon);
            foreach($categoriesas $category){
             $coupons->add($category->validCoupons());
            }
             //dd($coupons->first());  //dd#2
            if ($coupons->isNotEmpty()){
              $discountCalculator = resolve(DiscountCalculator::class);
              return $discountCalculator->discountedPrice($coupons->first() ,$price);
           }

        return $price ;

    }
    }
```

### Coupon

```
class Coupon extends Model
{
     public function isExpired()
     {
         return Carbon::now()->isAfter(Carbon::parse($this->expire_time));
     }
}
```

### Category

```
class Category extends Model
{
    use Couponable;
}
```

and this is Coponable:

```
trait Couponable
{
public function coupons()
{
    return $this->morphMany(Coupon::class , 'couponable');
}


public function validCoupons()
{
    return $this->coupons->where('expire_time' , '>' , Carbon::now());
}
```

}

but I get this error:

> Argument 1 passed to
> App\Support\Discount\DiscountCalculator::discountedPrice() must be an
> instance of App\Coupon, instance of
> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection given

I get to dd as As specified in question dd#1 and dd#2 and get the following results:

```
dd($categories->first()->validCoupons());
```

[image: first dd result]

and for dd#2:

```
dd($coupons->first());
```

[image: second dd result]

Answer (score 0):

As the error said the method `discountedPrice()` accepts `App\Coupon` as the first parameter and you gave it a `Collection`

```
$coupons = collect(new Coupon);
```

in this line you are making a new collection, then you `add()` coupons in that collection if you `dd($coupons)` you will find it's an instance of `Illuminate\Support\Collection` not `App\Coupon` so you need to pass `App\Coupon` instead as first parameter

Comment: I added dd results